# How to make grid sytem resposive in tailwind css

Tags: html, css

Hello hope are you well!
I am working on a component Vue.js, and  I am used utility  class tailwind CSS to styles.
Based on my task, I have to created a div as parent that include all children into div parent I have put md:grid-cols-4  md:grid-rows-4  I am sharing my code until now.

```html
  <div class="border-4 border-height  grid grid-cols-2  md:grid-cols-4 md:grid-rows-4  lg:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-rows-4  h-screen gap-1 p-2  justify-items-center items-center ">

      <div class="  border-6 border-secondary-400 w-full h-full row-start-1 row-span-3 "></div>
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-12 w-12 transform rotate-45 "></div>
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-22 w-22 "></div>
      <div class=" text-2xl font-semibold grid place-items-center">Emilia</div>   
   
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-22 w-22 "></div>
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 bg-primary h-12 w-12 transform rotate-45  "></div>  
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-22 w-22 "></div>     

      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400  bg-primary h-22 w-22 "></div>
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-22 w-22 "></div>
      <div class=" border-6 border-primary-400 h-12 w-12 transform rotate-45 "></div>    
      <div class=" text-2xl font-semibold grid place-items-center">Emilia</div> 
      <div class=" col-start-2 md:col-span-3  w-full h-full border-6 border-tertiary-400 "></div>
     
       

     <!-- you probably need a few more of these divs ... -->
   </div>
```

Also I am [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/AnaSmith123/pen/OJzBpvp) sharing link on codepene just for example:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/AnaSmith123/pen/OJzBpvp)

My problem is:
1.when I am on brekpoints 767 -640 md box go out of the border box or div parent

As you can see on image below:
I try to set a class in dev parent  border-height  and style with css when I have set height 100% ok it works for this specific breakpoints. I don't know if you have any a best solution? in my case to fixed this problem.
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aXFZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use @media query and pure css, at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) link you can find the docs. Or you can try by using [the tailwind overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow)